# TYPO3 how to add virtual column to the TCA?

Tags: php, typo3

how can I add an virtual column to the TCA (TYPO3 8)? I have in a 1:n table with data and I want to display the count of the data in the backend to current element.
I need something like this:

```
$fields = [
    'counts7d' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => 'last 7 days',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'none',
            'procFunc' => '\Namespace\MyClass->MyMethod',
            'readOnly' => true,
            'params' => [
                'period => '7d'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'counts30d' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => 'last 30 days',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'none',
            'procFunc' => '\Namespace\MyClass->MyMethod',
            'readOnly' => true,
            'params' => [
                'period => '30d'
            ]
        ]
    ],
];



pseudo function:
public function myMethod($element, $params){

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE pid=$element[uid] and date > $params[period]";

return sql_count…

}
```

The field should only be informative for the backend users.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

The TCA field type [user](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/User.html) is exactly what you are looking for:

```
'counts7d' => [
    'exclude' => false,
    'label' => 'last 7 days',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'user',
        'userFunc' => \Namespace\MyClass::class . '->MyMethod',
        'parameters' => [
            'period => '7d',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: thanks, but this approach expects that the data to display is already known (comes from the database table) and will only be formatted through the userFunc. Is there a way to dynamically calculate the data and not to fetch it from the expected database field "counts7d"

Comment: Not sure how you came to this conclusion. The `user` field was and is meant for arbitrary data, you don't have to base this on an existing field with the same name.

Comment: as i see in documentation you need database field for type user, so as i see atm your answer is wrong. (or i not understand something ;) )

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer is simply outdated by now but yeah, "none" would be better for completely virtual columns.

Answer (score 0):

The TCA field type [none](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/None.html) is exactly what you are looking for. Type none is the only type that does **not** necessarily need a database field. To manipulate it you can use **userFunc** which allow you to use custom php function.